# Android FirestorePagingAdapter from multiple ViewTypes

Tags: android, google-cloud-firestore, android-recyclerview

I’m trying to display different **views** in a  RecyclerView using the `FirestorePagingAdapter` basing on a field value returned from the database (which is `type`).
How can I modify this to set a specific view to the RecyclerView for each list item.
[image: Firestore Structure]

```
  FirestorePagingAdapter<FeedItem, FeedViewHolder> pagingAdapter = new FirestorePagingAdapter<FeedItem, FeedViewHolder>(options) {

            @NonNull
            @Override
            public FeedViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
                // HANDLE VIEW TYPE
                return null;
            }

            @Override
            protected void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull FeedViewHolder holder, int position, @NonNull FeedItem model) {
                // ADD DATA TO VIEW
            }
        };
```

Comment: If you understand Kotlin and you want to learn a modern way in which you can paginate Firestore documents, then this [resource](https://medium.com/firebase-tips-tricks/how-to-implement-pagination-in-firestore-using-jetpack-compose-76b4c0b5acd5) will help. Here is the corresponding [repo](https://github.com/alexmamo/FirestorePaginationJetpackCompose).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll need to implement `getItemViewType` in addition to the methods you already have.

The flow is that:

1. the adapter first calls your `getItemViewType` method with the position of the item it wants to render,
2. you then return a number that indicates the type of view you want to render for the position,
3. the adapter then calls `onCreateViewHolder` with the type,
4. you use that to create and return a view of the correct type, which
5. the adapter them passes to `onBindViewHolder`.

For examples of this, see:

- question: [onBindViewHolder and onCreateViewholder of FirebaseRecyclerAdapter are not getting called](https://stackoverflow.com/q/49256084)
- question: [How do I access the item in FirebaseRecycler's getItemViewType()?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51101803/how-do-i-access-the-item-in-firebaserecyclers-getitemviewtype)
- [comment in the repo](https://github.com/firebase/FirebaseUI-Android/issues/305#issuecomment-297231858) (which is for Realtime Database, but the flow is the same).